# LONG SHORT-TERM MEMORY Hochreiter's paper BPTT

Tags: lstm, backpropagation, mathematics

I was trying to read paper about LSTM, and I am stuck with mathematical problem.

http://www.bioinf.jku.at/publications/older/2604.pdf

page 4.

see,

|$f'_l$$_m$($net_l$$_m$)$w_l$$_m$ $_l$$_m$$_-$$_1$| is part of total error back flow.

|$f'_l$$_m$($net_l$$_m$)$w_l$$_m$ $_l$$_m$$_-$$_1$| is used for explaining about gradient vanishing, and exploding. 
(If |$f'_l$$_m$($net_l$$_m$)$w_l$$_m$ $_l$$_m$$_-$$_1$| > 1.0, gradient will explodes.)

$f_l$$_m$ is the logistic sigmoid function, then the maximal value of $f'_l$$_m$ is 0.25(which is alright), then |$f'_l$$_m$($net_l$$_m$)$w_l$$_m$ $_l$$_m$$_-$$_1$|  takes on maximal values where

$w_l$$_m$ $_l$$_m$$_-$$_1$ = $1/y^l$$^m$ $^-$ $^1$  $coth$(1/2net$_l$$_m$)

goes to zero for |$w_l$$_m$ $_l$$_m$$_-$$_1$| -> ∞

here is what I don't understand.

1.where is $coth$ coming from?

2. if |$w_l$$_m$ $_l$$_m$$_-$$_1$| is infinite, then why is |$f'_l$$_m$($net_l$$_m$)$w_l$$_m$ $_l$$_m$$_-$$_1$| = 0?

Comment: See https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/31449/hochreiter-lstm-p-4-maximal-values-of-logistic-sigmoid-derivative-times-weig/104068#104068